# How to fix div overlapping while using a customized div in a container-fluid (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am new to HTML, CSS and Bootstrap. I got the problem with overlapping divs when resize the screen to be smaller. The problem appeared when I used the container-fluid as a section and I used a customized div to have the header of the section. I tried to change the `display` property of my customized div (the header of the section) but it did not work. I have no idea where the problem. I hope you guys could hint me an idea to fix this one. Thank you all in advance and sorry if the question is a bit silly.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="home">
  <!--this div contain image on the left and information on the right-->
      <div class="row" id="main">
        <div class="col col-md-5 col-lg-5 col-12 order-1">
            <div class="lefside" id="show-image">
              <img src="images/coronavirus.png" alt="" width="600" height="400"></img>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-md-7 col-lg-7 col-12 order-2">
            <div class="information">
              <h1>Stay safe from Corona virus by keeping track of your locations!</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container-fluid" id="about">
      <div class="intro">
        <h1>What is this website about?</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="row function">
        <div class="col col-md-5 col-lg-5 col-12 order-1">
          <img src="images/community.png" alt="" style="width: 80%; height: 80%"></img>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-md-7 col-lg-7 col-12 order-2">
            <h2 style="text-align:center">Our mission</h2>
            <div class="mission">
              <p>The COVID-19 pandemic, also known as the coronavirus pandemic, is an ongoing global pandemic of coronavirus disease 2019 (COVID-19) caused by severe acute respiratory syndrome coronavirus 2 (SARS-CoV-2). The virus was first identified in December 2019 in Wuhan, China.
              <br>
              <br>
              We created this website to help you to keep track of visited location. You can see
              the current hotspots in the map to avoid the areas that are dangerous. Furthermore,
              you can keep track of the visited locations by entering the longitude and latitude
              of the location, therefore, you can check whether you have been to a hotspot!
              <br>
              <br>
              <span style="font-weight: bold">
                SIGN UP AND JOIN WITH US TO PROTECT THE COMMUNITY!
              </span>
              </p>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container-fluid" id="guideline">
      <div class="intro">
        <h1>How to use this website</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="row function">
          <div class="col col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-12 order-1">
              <div style="width: 100%; height: 50%">
                  <img src="images/login.png" alt="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></img>
              </div>
              <div class="guideline_text">
                <p>Log in by your account</p>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-12 order-2">
              <div style="width: 100%; height: 50%">
                  <img src="images/checkin.png" alt="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></img>
              </div>
              <div class="guideline_text">
                <p>Check-in locations by entering longitude and latitude</p>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-12 order-3">
              <div style="width: 100%; height: 50%">
                  <img src="images/seemap.png" alt="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></img>
              </div>
              <div class="guideline_text">
                <p>See your locations in the map with hotspots</p>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-12 order-4">
              <div style="width: 100%; height: 50%">
                  <img src="images/alert.jpg" alt="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></img>
              </div>
              <div class="guideline_text">
                <p>Check if you have been to a hotspot</p>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
.home{
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}

#main{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#show-image{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center ;
}

.information{
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

#about{
  height: 630px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;

}
#guideline{
  height: 500px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.intro{
  height: 63px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center ;
  background: grey;
}

.function{
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.mission{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
  align-items: left;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.guideline_text{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  padding-top: 50px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

The containers overlap each others when resize to the smaller screen. Again thank you all for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is to remove almost every time in CSS that you manually set the **height** property. I would advise to never do this if you can avoid it, especially for divs that just contain text.

I wish I could give a more academic answer, but I don't have the experience to do so.

You can read more [here](https://www.lifewire.com/set-height-html-element-100-percent-3467075) about setting the height property if you still desire to do so

Comment: Hi @ssbrear, thanks for pointing out the root of the problem for me. Yeah you are right, the problem is about setting ```height```, manually, I just try to delete all the ```height``` in my CSS and it works. However, I am not sure why. I have a question: If I do not set the ```height``` manually then the height of the div will be automatically expand according to the elements inside the div, doesn't it? Again, thank you a lot for helping me to find out the problem buddy!

Comment: No problem! You are correct when you say that the height will expand automatically. It seems that in this case if you allow the height to expand automatically, it will push the div below it, whereas if you set the height manually, it no longer has this effect and will just overwrite the element below it. This is honestly not the behavior I would expect. You can test it yourself by creating two square divs with different colors of 100px side lengths and then changing the height of the first to 200px. It won't overwrite the one below, like your code did. Perhaps something with bootstrap?

Comment: I see, that's definitely the problem here. Thank you a lot buddy!